# Accessing HTML5 data-* attribute after changing its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm using a data-count attribute to count how many times a list element has been dropped into a list of targets. The element can only be dropped into each target once, but can be dropped into multiple targets.

The problem is that I need to keep track and display a count. I'm using the data attribute and running into the following problem.

On the drop, I check the initial count with

```
var original_count = member.data('count');
```

If the count is zero, I add a class to the original element, and update its data attribute with

```
member.attr('data-count', 1);
```

This works fine, I can see the change in the DOM after dropping it once. When I go to drop it a second time...

```
member.data('count');
```

Returns the initial value of zero, instead of the updated value of 1. If I change the count checker to

```
var original_count = member.attr('data-count');
```

It returns zero every drop. I just need to be able to access the *updated* value of an html5 data attribute. Going to RTFM and see what I missed, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery caches the data values for faster access. Use `data(name, newvalue)` to set the values instead of attr.

Comment: I'd tried that initially, however if I set the new value using member.data('count', 1), the DOM doesn't update with the new value, and after the change, original_member.data('count'); returns 0 still on the initial check.

Comment: there is a issue with jquery data() method, access the value second time after updating using .attr('data-count'). see if it works

Comment: Of course it does not set the DOM, why do you want to set the DOM is beyond my understanding, the meaning of the data mechanism in JQuery is to allow some JavaScript data be tagged along DOM elements, not DOM modification. Just use data() everywhere, end of discussion.

Comment: That is my original issue. I tried using data everywhere and for some reason when accessing the data attribute *after* I've incremented it by 1, on subsequent drops, accessing it still returns zero. Going to inspect further.

Comment: You are **not** setting data using data(name, value) in your example in the question, thus not using the data() everywhere.

Comment: If you could post the code with .data() calls where you originally had issues we could advise on what's wrong with it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala must have mixed myself up in trying data vs attr and then trying to explain it. I will update my original question with some clarifications for anyone else who might have this issue and have accepted your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @amakhrov I will update my question here shortly with an explanation of what I ended up doing wrong